# Include Screen Options in WordPress Admin Dashboard

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I created a custom theme in WordPress. I'd like to add WooCommerce categories to my menu admin dashboard but "Product" and many other options won't appear in the "Screen Option" menu. What is the code I need to add to functions in order to display all of the Screen Options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check this options first.
[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for you reply. Turnt out it was just a user issue (It wasn't logged in as Admin so I couldn't see all the Options). Thanks for your reply!